# Grouping import statements in python

Tags: python, pylint

I have started learning python recently and ran pylint on my python file. I got following comments.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
```

I the above two lines, the Pylinter comment is

```
C:  5, 0: Imports from package os are not grouped (ungrouped-imports)
```

How can I achieve that ?

And another comment is in below line

```
import mimetypes, time, csv, platform, base64, django, sys, os, math, uuid, linecache, logging, requests

C:  5, 0: standard import "import mimetypes, time, csv, platform, base64, django, sys, os, math, uuid, linecache, logging, requests" should be placed before "import mimetypes, time, csv, platform, base64, django, sys, os, math, uuid, linecache, logging, requests" (wrong-import-order)
```

what does the above line mean and why is it required?

Comment: "I the above two lines i got group the two import statements together. How can I achieve that ?" I don't understand this question. Can you please [edit] to make it more clear.

Comment: It's not *required*. Pylint is about style issues, that's all.

Comment: According to PEP 8, the style guide for Python, you shouldn't group multiple imports like this, put them on separate lines instead.

Comment: Have a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Practically all Python linters check its rules, and you will get help much easier if you adhere to it.

Comment: "It's okay to say this though: `from subprocess import Popen, PIPE`" -- pep8. The linter is also saying all imports from os should be together. It doesn't recognise os and os.path as different modules.
`

Comment: @FHTMitchell I wasn't clear, I meant this line is wrong
`import mimetypes, time, csv, platform, base64, django, sys, os, math, uuid, linecache, logging, requests`
Or maybe not wrong but stylistically sub-optimal.

Comment: @mklucz I see. Apologies

Answer (score 13):

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) suggests to order and group imports like so:

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> 1. Standard library imports.
> 2. Related third party imports.
> 3. Local application/library specific imports.
>
> You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

In your case, django and requests are third party imports, and so you should write

```
import mimetypes, time, csv, platform, base64, sys, os, math, uuid, linecache, logging

import django, requests
```

It can further be useful to alphabetize imports (in each group) when you have this many.

Further, pylint seems to like grouping beyond PEP8. In particular, imports from the same module/package should be grouped together. That is, add a space between your `os` imports and the rest, and maybe even throw the bare `os` import up there as well. In all:

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

import base64, csv, linecache, logging, math, mimetypes, platform, time, sys, uuid

import django, requests
```

Comment: `import base64, csv, linecache, logging, math, mimetypes, platform, time, sys, uuid` this is very much discouraged by PEP8. These should all be separate import statements. PEP8: "Imports should usually be on separate lines:"

Comment: Indeed. I'm not sure if this is required by pylint though.

Comment: pylint grouping means only that the imports from the same package should be in **consecutive** lines, it is *not* needed to add any *spaces* between different groups though.